# How print SQL query in html from websocket server

Tags: javascript, html, json, python-3.x, mariadb

The Browser-based example from the [Getting started page](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html) is working well when I launch python websocket server. I've got the date as out put of the console.

So, I tried to modify it for getting a database query out put. I did my page like this :

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>WebSocket demo</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:5678/"),
                var mysql = require('mysql');
                var con = mysql.createConnection({
                         host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
                         user: "userdb",
                         password: "passwd",
                         database: "DB"
                });

                con.connect(function(err) {
                         if (err) throw err;
                console.log("Connected!");
                });

          </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've got a blank page. Notes, I put IP addrees as host value. I've got python script which are querying without problem on the same DB.

Comment: You're not using your websocket server here. This code tries to connect to mysql from the browser (and I think you'll see some errors in the browser console)

Comment: As I told I got white page. There is nothing on it.

Comment: On the page, yes. What about JS console?

Comment: On firefox I've got this : SyntaxError: missing variable name with a link to this [page ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/No_variable_name?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=firefox-console-errors&utm_campaign=default)

Comment: On chrome I've got this Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var

Answer (score 0):

1. Look at the token before each "var".
2. Review the syntax rules for Javascript.

Need I guide you further?